# Getting AWS Dynamodb query result as internel server error code : 502

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

This is my table "odo":

[image]

I want to retrive data where deviceId == 'A233' Between two timestamps. I run query inside Lamda Function and testing with API Gateway.

This is query I ran to get the result:

```
var params = {
    TableName: "odo",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#deviceId = :deviceIdVal AND #timestamp BETWEEN :sdate AND :edate",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#deviceId": "deviceId",
        "#timestamp": "timestamp"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":deviceIdVal": 'A233',
        ":sdate": 1110601808,
        ":edate": 1522902606
    }
};
```

But I get a error as "**Internal Server Error**" and Error Code : 502

**Why this query won't work? What am I missing?**

When I ran another query using id field,it work.

```
module.exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    console.log(event);
    let _response = "";
    let invalid_path_err = {
        "Error": "Invalid path request " + event.resource + ', ' +
        event.httpMethod
    };
    if(event.resource === '/odos' && event.httpMethod === "GET"){
        var params = {
            TableName: "odo",
            KeyConditionExpression: "#id = :id",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#id": "id"
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":id": 7
            }
        };



        docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log("Query succeeded.",data);
                _response = buildOutput(200, data);
                return callback(null, _response);
            }
        });

    }
    else {
        _response = buildOutput(500, {"error 500" : "invalid_path_err"});
        return callback(_response, null);
    }
};
/* Utility function to build HTTP response for the microservices output */
function buildOutput(statusCode, data) {
    let _response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    return _response;
};
```

This is the success result in test method execution in API Gateway:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your query is trying to use a table partition key of `deviceid` and a range key of `timestamp`. In fact you have a parition key called `id` and no range key.

You can only use `KeyConditionExpression` on attributes that are a key, which in your case is the attribute `id`.

To do your 'query' you need to change `KeyConditionExpression` to `FilterExpression` and change `query` to `scan`

EDIT:

```
module.exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    console.log(event);
    let _response = "";
    let invalid_path_err = {
        "Error": "Invalid path request " + event.resource + ', ' +
        event.httpMethod
    };
    if(event.resource === '/odos' && event.httpMethod === "GET"){
        var params = {
            TableName: "odo",
            FilterExpression: "#deviceId = :deviceIdVal AND #timestamp BETWEEN :sdate AND :edate",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#deviceId": "deviceId",
                "#timestamp": "timestamp"
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":deviceIdVal": 'A233',
                ":sdate": 1110601808,
                ":edate": 1522902606
            }
        };



        docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log("Query succeeded.",data);
                _response = buildOutput(200, data);
                return callback(null, _response);
            }
        });

    }
    else {
        _response = buildOutput(500, {"error 500" : "invalid_path_err"});
        return callback(_response, null);
    }
};
/* Utility function to build HTTP response for the microservices output */
function buildOutput(statusCode, data) {
    let _response = {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    return _response;
};
```

Comment: could you please write a query for me? I tried googling of way of using Filter Expression. But I could not understand how to write a query for my problem.

Comment: Please post your query that works as code (not an image) and I will update that.

Comment: have a go with that